# Restkit: Assertion failure in -[RKObjectMappingProvider mappingForPatternMatchingString:context:]

Tags: objective-c, restkit

I'm using restkit trying to serialize an object after I do a PUT request, and I'm getting the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Cannot look up mapping matching nil pattern string.'
```

How can I fix this?

My serialization mapping is just an inverse mapping of the object mapping, and I know the object mapping works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was modifying the loader's URL in the block of `putObject:usingBlock:` and I replaced it with a NSURL, not a RKURL like restkit was expecting.

It probably tried to assign the variable `resourcePath` based upon a property that RKURL has and NSURL lacks. `resourcePath` was then used as the pattern string, and was of course nil.

I'm still able to modify the loader's URL, but now that I assign it a RKURL everything works.

Answer (score 0):

i was getting this error when

```
[self.responseObjectManager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:nil usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader * loader){}];
```

so changed it to

```
[self.responseObjectManager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"" usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader * loader){}];
```